# Get greatest values only from one table

Tags: mysql

I got two tables A and B:

A:

```
id v1
-----
1  12
2  9   (added after edit)
2  11
3  27    
3  23
```

B:

```
id v2
-----
1  13
3  10
2  10    
3  28
```

I want to select every row from B, where v2 is greatest from all v2,v1 corresponding to the id from both tables. (EDIT: What I mean: Show me every row from B which includes the single maximum value for that id from both tables).

The result should look like this:

```
id  greatest (v1,v2)
--------------------
1  13
3  28
```

So far I am able to show the greatest from both tables with:

```
select distinct a.id, greatest(v1,v2) from a join b on a.id=b.id group by a.id;
```

Which leads to:

```
id  greatest (v1,v2)
--------------------
1  13
2  11
3  28
```

Any ideas on how to show greatest(v1,v2) from B only?

Comment: So part of the criteria is that v2 must be greater than v1 (for the same id)

Comment: Yes. I'll edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: I see. You want rows where the maximum value of a is less than or equal to b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

```
SELECT b.id
     , MAX(v2) v2 
  FROM b 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT id
            , MAX(v1) v1 
         FROM a 
        GROUP 
           BY id
     ) x 
    ON x.id = b.id 
   AND x.v1 <= b.v2 
 GROUP 
    BY id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that does not work yet. My first example was bad, sorry for that. With that code, I also get rows from b if v2 is bigger than any corresponding value for the id from a. In the updated example this results to the row (2, 10) which should not be in the result.

Comment: @JanT. See edit - although I'm not 100% sure that it's right.